# Getting this error npm ERR! Failed at the build:dev script

Tags: node.js, npm

I am running this command **npm run build:dev**. Getting Below error

$ npm run build:dev

> @ build:dev D:\project
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack && node react/scripts/build.dev.js

```
 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! build:dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack && node react/scripts/build.dev.js`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the build:dev script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR! C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-22T07_04_41_953Z-debug.log
```

Using node version : v10.16.0 and npm version : 6.9.0

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What happens when you write `node --version` in the terminal.

Comment: I am getting node version as  v10.16.0

Comment: I'm not sure if this will change anything but maybe try appending ./ to the path of the script. Or maybe try running the command `node react/scripts/build.dev.js` to see if it works

Comment: In package.json , I have scripts like this   
"scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack && node react/scripts/build.js",
    "build:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack && node react/scripts/build.dev.js"
}

Comment: Does the regular build script work?

Comment: I am running build:dev script. I didn't check regular build script

Comment: I know...but try running other scripts, that way we can see what works and what doesn't

Comment: Runned build script. Now I am getting error like this npm ERR!  build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack && node react/scripts/build.js`

Comment: Ok...and what happens when you try running `node react/scripts/build.js` from the terminal?